# search lists and return values excel

Tags: excel

So, I had data like this, its pretty easy to do in python but not sure why its not working in excel. I used this formula. I want to classify lead locations into team column.

Input lead location and pre-defined apac, emea and america list.

expected output: Team column

Is there any way to do it?

[image]

False? i dont get it...

```
=IF(COUNTIF($D2,E:E)>0, "APAC", (IF(COUNTIF($D2,F:F)>0, "EMEA", IF(COUNTIF($D2,G:G)>0, "NONE" ))))
```

| Lead Location | APAC | EMEA | AMERICA | `Team` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dubai | Dubai | Toronto | Warsaw | APAC |
| Bangalore | Bangalore | Brazil | Frankfurt | APAC |
| Mumbai | Mumbai |  | Peru | APAC |
| Warsaw |  |  |  | AMERICA |
| Frankfurt |  |  |  | AMERICA |
| Bangalore |  |  |  | APAC |
| Toronto |  |  |  | EMEA |
| Brazil |  |  |  | EMEA |
| Peru |  |  |  | AMERICA |
| Bangalore |  |  |  | APAC |

Comment: What is your excel version?

Comment: excel version: 2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below formula-

```
=INDEX($B$1:$D$1,1,MATCH(1,MMULT({1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},--($B$2:$D$11=A2)),0))
```

[image]

Comment: thank you! I will investigate the logic of this.